# How can I directly use url to access my spring boot web application without any port?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ubuntu, spring-security

I have deployed my spring boot application which using spring security for security in a ubuntu server.So, I have an problem.I can only access my application with using url like:https://example.com:8443. As for, why do I use the port of 8443?It is seems that spring security using the port of 8443.Is there any solutions help me to access my application with url of [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)?
my related code is as follows:

```
spring.freemarker.cache=false
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://MyIp:3306/keziqu?serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
server.port=8443
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:**.pfx
server.ssl.key-store-password=password
#server.ssl.key-password=another-secret
logging.file.path=./log/
#logging.level.org.springframework.security=debug
```

```
@Configuration
public class TomcatConfig {

    @Bean
    TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory(){
            @Override
            protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
                SecurityConstraint constraint = new SecurityConstraint();
                constraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");
                SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
                collection.addPattern("/*");
                constraint.addCollection(collection);
                context.addConstraint(constraint);
            }
        };
        factory.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(createTomcatConnector());
        return factory;
    }

    private Connector createTomcatConnector() {
        Connector connector = new
                Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
        connector.setScheme("http");
        connector.setPort(80);
        connector.setSecure(false);
        connector.setRedirectPort(8443);
        return connector;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to visit your website without having to specify the port, you need to make sure it's running on the *default* port.

The default **secured HTTP** *(https://)* port is **443**.

The default **unsecured HTTP** *(http://)* port is **80**.

Comment: I assume server.port=443 and connector.setRedirectPort(443)